# What is the LINQ to Objects equivalent of F#'s Seq.cache?

Tags: linq, f#

What is the LINQ to Objects equivalent of F#'s [Seq.cache](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#cache), which does the following:

> Returns a sequence that corresponds to a cached version of the input sequence. The result sequence will have the same elements as the input sequence. The result can be enumerated multiple times. The input sequence will be enumerated at most once and only as far as is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like MoreLinq's [Memoize](https://morelinq.github.io/3.0/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_Experimental_ExperimentalEnumerable_Memoize__1.htm) does this.

> Creates a sequence that lazily caches the source as it is iterated for the first time, reusing the cache thereafter for future re-iterations. If the source is already cached or buffered then it is returned verbatim.